# Xamarin.Forms - ListView shows up in UWP but not Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, uwp

I've searched the internets and reviewed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) document at Microsoft but I still can't get my ListView to display on Android. It shows up fine in UWP though. Any assistance would be great. In case you are wondering where my RaisePropertyChanges are, I am using PropertyChanged.Fody.

ViewModel:

```
public class AssignmentsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IAssignmentDataService assignmentDataService;

    public ObservableCollection<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Assignment>();

    public AssignmentsViewModel()
    {
        assignmentDataService = App.IoCContainer.Get<IAssignmentDataService>();

        LoadAssignmentsAsync();
    }

    private async Task LoadAssignmentsAsync()
    {
        Assignments = new ObservableCollection<Assignment>(await assignmentDataService.GetAssignments());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

View (using MainPage for testing purposes):

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Assignments}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Content}"
                              TextColor="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

View (Code Behind):

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new AssignmentsViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to force TextCell height by Height property? Did the rest of the screen is visible on android? maybe you see it on landscape but not in portrait. Why is the listview inside a grid?

Comment: @FabriBertani I originally had a Label bound to a string property to verify my databinding works. But I will try that when I get home and report back.